# Drop down menu alignment IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, menu

Sorry if this has already been asked but I couldnt find an answer which fixed my issue. I have created a drop down menu which works fine in all browsers apart from IE. I have added a width to the menu li item so that they fill the width of the page. This has made the sub menu not float correctly in IE - instead of floating directly under the ul item it floats underneth but to the right. It works fine if I remove the width of the menu li but I need this otherwise the menu just bunches to the left.

Thank you in advance

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page1.php">Page 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page3.php">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul><!--menu-->
```

And my css:

```
/*----- Drop down menu styling -----*/

.menu { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
 }
.menu li { 
  list-style:none; 
  float:left; 
  font:0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  color: #fff; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: 240px; 
 }
.menu li a:link, .menu li a:visited { 
  display:block; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  background-color: #88cb78; 
  padding: 0.5em 2em; 
  margin:0; 
  border-right: 1px solid #fff; 
  color:#fff; 
 }
.menu li a:hover { 
  background-color:#a8db9b; 
 }

/*----- sub menu styling -----*/
.menu li ul {
  font:0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  position:absolute; 
  float: left; 
  visibility:hidden; 
  border-top:1px solid #fff; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  background-color: #88cb78; 
 }
.menu li ul li { 
  display:inline; 
  float:none; 
 }
.menu li ul li a:link, .menu li ul li a:visited { 
  background-color: #88cb78; 
  width:auto; 
 }
.menu li ul li a:hover { 
  background-color:#a8db9b; 
 }
```

Comment: If you are using absolute position, use positioning values `top:100%, left:0` instead of `float:left`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that just makes the drop down not show at all.

Comment: You've probably still got visibility hidden or haven't set the parent to `position:relative`

Comment: Hi Paulie, Thanks that now works... the only issue is that when the page loads the drop down menu is showing by default instead of on hover. If I hover over another main menu item it goes. But guessing this is something I need to change in the javascript in document ready...?

Comment: If you are using JS to control the menu then yes.

Comment: Thank you, have changed the visibility to hidden for the li ul in css and now all working as it should. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this example.

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
}
.menu li a:link,
.menu li a:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #88cb78;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #a8db9b;
}
/*----- sub menu styling -----*/

.menu li ul {
  font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #88cb78;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu li ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}
.menu li ul li a:link,
.menu li ul li a:visited {
  background-color: #88cb78;
  width: auto;
}
.menu li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #a8db9b;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/page1.php">Page 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/page2.php">Page 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/page3.php">Page 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--menu-->
```

Comment: Thank you that has nearly fixed it! Menu works as it should in IE now but when the sub menu drops down is pushes the rest of the page down. Then it moves back up when i'm not hovering... This is now in all browsers... I tried adding a z-index but that didnt work...

Comment: @jenna i edited my above answer. i think now it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but has been fixed with comments above.

Comment: @Jenna if my answer helps you than you can accept it.